# Is there a way to pass a JsonSerializable object as an array parameter?

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.3

I'm in the process of updating a REST Api class; at the end of each method, I have to call the `DoResponse` method to transform the data I pass as the first parameter into a JSON string.

As part of the requirements, I created response objects for each endpoint; all of these objects implement `\JSONSerializable`

```php
class CustomResponseObject implements JsonSerializable {
    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [/*...*/];
    }
}
```

I then instantiate those objects in my Api method and pass it to the `DoResponse` function.

```php
function myApiEndpoint() {
    $res = new CustomResponseObject();
    /*...*/
    return $this->DoResponse($res);
}
```

Problem is, said method only accepts arrays as the first parameter.

```php
public function DoResponse(array $response = array());
```

I could work around the problem by passing `$res->jsonSerialize()`, but is there a way to automatically jsonSerialize the object whenever I pass it to the `DoResponse` function without changing the underlying methods?

Comment: `return $this->DoResponse([$res]);`

Comment: @EmptyBrain I'm sorry but this would change the response content, and it's unacceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution we decided to adopt is to change the signature and the first few lines of the `DoResponse()` method like this:

```php
public function DoResponse($response = array()) {
    if($response instanceof JsonSerializable) {
        $response = $response->jsonSerialize();
    }
    if(is_array($response) === false) {
        // Error handling
    }

    // Previous function body.
}
```

Nothing exciting but apparently there's no way, at the moment, to make the process completely automatic.